# Log Normal Distrubution best fit

Tags: probability-distributions

Hello math geniuses!  Compsci dude here.

I'm trying to model the price distribution of a category of goods, and figure a LogNormalDistribution would provide a good fit.  The problem is, I don't know how to do this with the data I have available.

I have several data points available:  C(x1) to C(xn).  For a given x, C(x) is the cumulative percentage of all items cheaper than x dollars.  That is, if C(x) = .5, x is the median.

Given points C(x1) to C(xn), how can I find the best fit Log Normal Distribution?  I suppose the question really is:  how do I find the best fit log normal cumulative distribution function for a given set of points, and how "good" will the fit be?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: You might try math.stackexchange

Comment: Is MathOverflow the more advanced version of math.stackexchange?  Please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Yes.  From the faq, "MathOverflow's primary goal is for users to ask and answer _research level math questions_, the sorts of questions you come across when you're writing or reading articles or graduate level books."

Comment: Or even try http://stats.stackexchange.com, which is better for statistical questions

Answer (score 1):

A simple estimation:

1) $y_i=\log(x_i)$

2) $\hat\mu = \sum_i y_i (F((y_i+y_{i+1})/2)-F((y_i+y_{i-1})/2)$

3) $\hat\sigma= (\sum_i y_i^2 (F((y_i+y_{i+1})/2)-F((y_i+y_{i-1})/2)) -\mu^2$.

Then $x \sim \mathrm{Lognormal}(\hat\mu,\hat\sigma)$

Comment: What function is F() ?